# Scan FingerPrint and Send Credential to Outside server in Android

Tags: android, authentication, fingerprint

recently I am Stuck with Scanning Fingerprint. After Lots of Googling I conclude that finger-Print cant be take in **Marshmallow** or Greater Version of Android.

Other thing I conclude that you can not store fingerprint image to Outside server like **MYSQL (via web-service )** when you scan it with inbuilt sensor.

so, Anybody have any idea about how i can store finger print and use it in my app for authenticate user.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're right with embedded fingerprint you could only match current user of device.

If you need to store fingerprint data in database to match user after then read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_recognition
It's better to store template than image because size of template is lower.

You need an external fingerprint reader with a specific SDK.
For instance:

- http://www.dermalog.com/en/products_solutions/fingerprintscanner/
- http://www.futronic-tech.com/product_fs80h.html
- http://www.crossmatch.com/authentication-hardware/

Comment: @AjeyMistry ,  is it useful ?